# mysql if then statement not working?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, strcmp

Am I blind, or what is wrong with my query?

```
select 
    STRCMP( message, 'LogMessage') = 1
from 
    LogEntries;
```

works fine. However

```
select 
    IF STRCMP( message, 'LogMessage') = 1 THEN 'bla' END IF
from 
    LogEntries;
```

returns:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'STRCMP( message, 'LogMessage') = 1 THEN 'bla' END IF from 
>     LogEntries' at line 2

What is wrong with this statement?

Comment: The syntax is `IF(STRCMP( message, 'LogMessage'), 'bla', null)` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Oh man, thanks :) Hmm, confusing, because I had a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html . Although my resource is the wrong page.

Comment: As the documentations says, one thing is the `IF` statement, and a different one is the `IF` function. In this case you need the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN STRCMP( message, 'LogMessage') = 1 THEN 'bla' END AS your_column
FROM
  LogEntries;
```

when the condition is true it will return 'bla' otherwise, since there's no else part, it will return NULL.